# Splunk get inner Query results with in the time frame provided by outer Query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Successfully scheduled PushNotification in UserMessageChanelMap LINK_MORE_ACCOUNTS |eval fields=split(*raw,"|") | eval messageKey* =mvindex(fields,2) |eval num=mvindex(fields,5) | table messageKey_, num | eval scheduledDate = replace(num, "scheduledDate:", "") | eval messageKey = replace(messageKey_,"messageKey:","")  | eval  newTS=strftime(strptime(scheduledDate, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | stats count by newTS,messageKey | stats min(newTS) as fromScheduledDate, max(newTS) as toScheduledDate | appendcols [search  (  ("*Could not send PushNotification*")  messageKey:LINK_MORE_ACCOUNTS  NOT ("*|reason:Failed to Deliver|") | extract pairdelim="|" kvdelim=":"   | table userId,userMessageId,messageKey|  stats count  by userId,userMessageId,messageKey | table userId,userMessageId, messageKey | stats count as pushFallOffPoints by messageKey ]

Here I want to run my SubQuery with in the time range of fromScehduledDate  - toScehduledDate. I was trying to pass these dates to earliest and latest but that did not work. Help is appreciated .

Comment: The second `stats` line stomps on the first one, as it stands now: `| stats count by newTS,messageKey | stats min(newTS) as fromScheduledDate, max(newTS) as toScheduledDate`. You're only going to get 2 results from the second `stats` - so either don't bother with the first, or you need to rethink what you want the second grouped by. I *suspect* you meant this: `| stats min(newTS) as fromScheduledDate, max(newTS) as toScheduledDate` by messageKey`

Answer (score 0):

Subsearches run first so there is no such thing as passing fields *into* a subsearch.  A subsearch, however, can return fields to the main search using the `format` or `return` command.  Run the subsearch by itself to see what exactly it returns and to verify the returned string makes sense when combined with the main search.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution

( [ search Successfully scheduled PushNotification in  LINK_MORE_ACCOUNTS |eval fields=split(*raw,"|") | eval messageKey* =mvindex(fields,2) |eval num=mvindex(fields,5) | table messageKey_, num | eval scheduledDate = replace(num, "scheduledDate:", "") | eval messageKey = replace(messageKey_,"messageKey:","")  | eval  newTS=strptime(scheduledDate, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y") | stats count by newTS,messageKey | stats min(newTS) as earliest | return  earliest  ]
, [ search Successfully scheduled PushNotification in UserMessageChanelMap LINK_MORE_ACCOUNTS |eval fields=split(*raw,"|") | eval messageKey* =mvindex(fields,2) |eval num=mvindex(fields,5) | table messageKey_, num | eval scheduledDate = replace(num, "scheduledDate:", "") | eval messageKey = replace(messageKey_,"messageKey:","")  | eval  newTS=strptime(scheduledDate, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y") | stats count by newTS,messageKey | stats max(newTS) as latest | return latest] )
( container_name="ace-service")  ("*Could not send PushNotification*")  messageKey:LINK_MORE_ACCOUNTS  NOT ("*|reason:Failed to Deliver|") | extract pairdelim="|" kvdelim=":"   | table userId,userMessageId,messageKey|  stats count  by userId,userMessageId,messageKey | table userId,userMessageId, messageKey | stats count as pushFallOffPoints by messageKey